# Optional properties depending on other property

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have the following Typescript `interface`:

```
interface Sample {
    key1: boolean;
    key2?: string;
    key3?: number;
};
```

In this case, `key1` is always required, `key2` is always optional, while key3 should exist if `key1` is `true` and should not exist if `key1` is `false`. In another word, a key's occurrence depends on another key's value. How can we achieve this in Typescript?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The most straightforward way to represent this is with a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead of an interface:

```
type Sample = {
  key1: true,
  key2?: string,
  key3: number
} | {
  key1: false,
  key2?: string,
  key3?: never
}
```

In this case the type alias is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of two types you're describing.  So a `Sample` should be either the first constituent (where `key1` is true and `key3` is required) or the second constituent (where `key1` is false and `key3` is absent).

Type aliases are similar to interfaces but they are not completely interchangeable.  If using a type alias leads to some kind of error, please add more detail about your use case in the question.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: this is a nice one

Comment: This is just the best!!!

Comment: Works! But I deleted key3?: never completely

Comment: It's up to you; if you leave off `never` then you allow [this behavior](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4noW).  This may or many not matter to you.

Answer (score 6):

I also really like the way Ben Ilegbodu (https://www.benmvp.com/blog/conditional-react-props-typescript/) does it:

Give these three different cases in JSX:

```
<Text>not truncated</Text>
<Text truncate>truncated</Text>
<Text truncate showExpand>truncated w/ expand option</Text>
```

... Here is the corresponding TypeScript definition to make the `showExpanded` property required when the `truncate` prop is present:

````
interface CommonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode

  // ...other props that always exist
}

type TruncateProps =
  | { truncate?: false; showExpanded?: never }
  | { truncate: true; showExpanded?: boolean }

type Props = CommonProps & TruncateProps

const Text = ({ children, showExpanded, truncate }: Props) => {
  // Both truncate & showExpanded will be of
  // the type `boolean | undefined`
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

I think that a readable solution is to use [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

so we can do this:

```
type IOverload = {
  (param: { arg1: number }): any;
  (param: { arg1: number; arg2: string; arg3: number }): any;
};

const sample: IOverload = (args) => {...};

sample({ arg1: 1, arg2: 'a' });

===> Property 'arg3' is missing in type '{ arg1: number; arg2: string; }' but required 
in type '{ arg1: number; arg2: string; arg3: number; }'.
```