# Is there a way to change whether an interface property is optional or not based on the value of another property(TypeScript)?

Tags: angular, typescript

Assuming I have an Interface:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  a?:string;
  b?:string;
}
```

So far both interface properties are optional. What I want is when **a** is set to any value then **b** to become required. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a `type` alias instead of an `interface`?  `type MyInterface = {a: string, b: string} | {a?: undefined, b?: string}`?  Let me know if that works; if not, please elaborate how.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @jcalz, your example works, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Typescript interface optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412872/typescript-interface-optional-properties-depending-on-other-property)

This question has been ask and answered here before. If you have more questions regarding interfaces with typescript refer to the documentation here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Best of luck!