# In Typescript how to make a property required if another optional property is set?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am not sure, what to search for below requirement. I am using the below type for react props.

```
interface ComponentProps {
   message : string,
   minValue? : number,
   minValueValidationMessage? :string
}
```

Now, I want to let the typescript know that, if `minValue` is specified then `minValueValidationMessage` should also be required.

if `minValueValidationMessage` is specified, then `minValue` should also be specified.

I have quite a few similar such combinations and can happen in any permutation and combination.

Comment: maybe you're after this: [Typescript interface optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412935) (might be difficult to scale though)

Comment: Thanks Nick. The scaling part of it is the problem. I have say 5 validation messages and validation values, creating a combination becomes a pain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the below one.

```
interface ComponentProps {
   message : string,
   min? : {value : number, validationMessage : string},
   max? : {value : number, validationMessage : string},
}
```

When using props you can specify

```
<Component 
    message={"Hello World"} 
    min={{value:10,vaidationMessage:"Value should be more than 10"}}
/>
```

If `{value : number, validationMessage : string}` repeats then it can be extracted to separate type.

Answer (score 1):

I like Vuetify's take on textfield validation

They declare `rules` prop on a textfield, that returns `true` if rule is passed or error string if not

```
// T will be type of value you want to validate, string for textfield for example
type ValidationRule<T> = (value: T) => true | string;
 
interface ComponentProps {
  message: string;
  rules: ValidationRule<string>[]
}
```

So now you can describe validation rules in parent component like so

```
<Component rules={[
  (value) => !!value || 'This field is required!',
  (value) => value.length < 10 || 'Length should be lesser than 10'
]}>
```

And loop through validaion rules inside the component to validate and display validation message

Comment: Interesting pattern. Thanks!

Comment: This solves another class of problems related to validation. But, the question I asked was around Typescript types and the other answer, solved that precisely