# one field is required if other is provided

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type

```
type myType{
 ....
 counter?: number,
 maxCount?: number,
}
```

with counter being required if (and only if) maxCount is provided.
What are the options to specify it in typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript how to make a property required if another optional property is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874558/in-typescript-how-to-make-a-property-required-if-another-optional-property-is-se)

Comment: Use a discriminated union type: https://css-tricks.com/typescript-discriminated-unions/

Comment: You need a union type of some sort.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/W4xlOW) is one way to do it.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please notify me via a mention of @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: `counter` is optional and can be provided even if `maxCount` is not provided, correct?

Comment: Oh, if that's true, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nakq2W) would be my suggestion. @GRZa, could you confirm (or deny)?

Comment: In my specific case, counter should not be provided if maxCount is not, but I wanted to find out both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `MyType` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where one member of the union requires the relevant properties, while the other member either *prohibits* them or makes them [*optional*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), depending on the use case.

TypeScript doesn't have an "official" or direct syntax for prohibiting a property. Merely leaving the property out of the type definition doesn't really have this effect, especially with unions.  See [Why does A | B allow a combination of both, and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218) for more information.

Instead, you can make the property optional with a value of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Since you cannot find a value of the `never` type, an optional property of type `never` can only meaningfully be satisfied by not including the property at all.

I'd recommend making a base type that your union members extend.

```
interface BaseMyType {
  someProp: string;
  counter?: number;
  maxCount?: number;
}
```

---

If you want to allow either *both* `maxCount` and `counter` or *neither* of them to appear, then you can do it like this:

```
interface MyTypeWithCounter extends BaseMyType {
  counter: number,
  maxCount: number
}

interface MyTypeWithoutCounter extends BaseMyType {
  counter?: never,
  maxCount?: never;
}

type MyType = MyTypeWithCounter | MyTypeWithoutCounter
```

And test it:

```
let myType: MyType;
myType = { someProp: "abc", counter: 123, maxCount: 456 }; // okay
myType = { someProp: "abc", maxCount: 456 }; // error
myType = { someProp: "abc", counter: 123, }; // error
myType = { someProp: "abc", }; // okay
```

---

On the other hand, if you just want to make sure that `counter` appears if `maxCount` does, and otherwise `counter` should be allowed but not required, then you can write it this way:

```
interface MyTypeWithMaxCount extends BaseMyType {
  counter: number,
  maxCount: number
}

interface MyTypeWithoutMaxCount extends BaseMyType {
  maxCount?: never;
}

type MyType = MyTypeWithMaxCount | MyTypeWithoutMaxCount
```

And test it:

```
let myType: MyType;
myType = { someProp: "abc", counter: 123, maxCount: 456 }; // okay
myType = { someProp: "abc", maxCount: 456 }; // error
myType = { someProp: "abc", counter: 123, }; // okay
myType = { someProp: "abc", }; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgEID2ALgBYDyATgHIQCW9ETe+hRSdsBrcAZuSQUQUCAFkAngBV5MZAQECoVSAAUmVGAC4kUGkyEBzANz8N8KgFdh3APzHgDsACNuNjUTAQAA8AYUdhN2JPHyY-AQBfPg0hESZxRCQFZVUAdU46MKdUpAggkWAAEyhJaTklFTVbAXsi7ndo7gAaJoDgwuF2724mxKaUsQkshrz6Rxp+4tLyqpqZKdVefyQW5yZI4AgANy6epEDQ8Jp9o98RpIEaBsz6jYBeZ+yIGYLL7iQAHw+03ycwWww0GAgNDOLwgxnWEBsTTAsKQ71wJm0ED0BmMACIQF54HjOttfkxjABGABMAGZSecFsYACwAVgAbEh4lYkAB6XlIKgAaxA8mRqPRmN0+iMSAJRJJZz6lxZHK5PP5JSY+iY4s+aLwUuxMvxhOJpJ2qSpdNJ3L5Au4Or1T0lWmluLlZsVds1wtF91GRBI0DgGRYVFkyqK31B5N4Y126UotQRm38buNHtM5mA1lOltcgxicQ0jMu+w6sTuCdSSaBuXykYuRRKZQglWqUjWqPU-gLFKiQyY3S2ZaKRfBCXuRHGaUmsJjDhoTYWreWnZTPdOY4i7huVY0gYeT1T7wR3xXlwB9a+IKXl6KTUh0JRn3hsKRpYlhozONl8vNMlWgHGl6SVZsBiQNlOR9AU-TFL99VdLE-1NBUGSjSDoPVe0tSdRCXR-FCTU9dCgN2a0wNgwURQQgRX0IjFfxIgDvQ1ODaL4fhRniIA)