# Optional properties on TypeScript union OR types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

EDIT: Added full example

I'm trying to more strictly define an object type with optional properties for React props using TypeScript (original answer I used here - [Typescript interface optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412872/typescript-interface-optional-properties-depending-on-other-property)):

```
export enum IXDirection {
    Right  = "right"
  , Center = "center"
  , Left   = "left"
};

export interface IFieldOption {
    label: string
  , value: string | number
};

export enum TFilterType {
    Date         = "date"
  , Input        = "input"
  , Select       = "select"
  , AutoComplete = "autocomplete"
}

type IDataTableColumnGeneric = {
    heading : string | null
  , width?  : string
  , align?  : IXDirection
  , onOrder?: (value: "asc" | "desc") => void
};

type TDataTableColumnFilter = {
    filterType?   : TFilterType.Date | TFilterType.Input
  , filterOptions?: never
  , onInputChange?: never
} | {
    filterType    : TFilterType.Select
  , filterOptions : IFieldOption[]
  , onInputChange?: never
} | {
    filterType    : TFilterType.AutoComplete
  , filterOptions?: IFieldOption[]
  , onInputChange : (value: string) => void
};

export type IDataTableColumn = IDataTableColumnGeneric & TDataTableColumnFilter;
```

With the above, I hope to ensure that certain filter types include certain properties while others should not. In using a simple example to test this:

```
const data = {
        heading   : "Date"
      , filterType: TFilterType.Date
      , width     : "100px"
      , onOrder   : (value: "asc" | "desc") => {}
};

function test(data: IDataTableColumn) {
  console.log(data);
}

test(data);
```

The above example should use `heading` in `IDataTableColumnGeneric` and the **first** type in `IDataTableColumnFilter` in using `filterType` as `TFilterType.Date` which essentially should mean that `filterOptions` and `onInputChange` must be `undefined` or not passed. There is a longer error here related to other parts using the same type but the major issue I've picked up:

```
Property 'onInputChange' is missing in type '{ heading: string; filterType: TFilterType; width: string; onOrder: (value: "asc" | "desc") => void; }' but required in type '{ filterType: TFilterType.AutoComplete; filterOptions?: IFieldOption[] | undefined; onInputChange: ((value: string) => void) | undefined; }'.
```

I've tried using `string`s in place of the `enum` but it gives a similar error relating to strings of course. Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: [Simplified example](https://tsplay.dev/mLLDAm)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m3abEw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz - [example](https://tsplay.dev/mLLDAm)

Comment: Could you put that example in the question itself and not only in a comment?  Your issue is that your `data` is not typed strongly enough; if you write `const foo = {bar: "baz"}` the compiler will infer it to be of type `{bar: string}` and not `{bar: "baz"}`; if you want something more specific, you have to do something else, like [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)... [observe](https://tsplay.dev/WJRQkW). Does that work for you? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: Interesting formatting

Comment: I think you're looking for const assertion here `filterType: TFilterType.Date as const`, as @jcalz suggested

Comment: That worked a treat! But... @jcalz is there a way I can build something into the type so it happens automatically?

Comment: Please put the actual plain text of the [mre] into the question itself; an external link is a good supplement to, but not a replacement for, the plaintext version.  (You shouldn't be required to follow links outside of SO to understand the question).  I can do it for you if you want.

Comment: "Is there a way I can build something into the type so it happens automatically?" I don't quite understand the question, sorry.  Which type would you build something into?  There's nothing you can do to the definition of `IDataTableColumn` which will have an "automatic" effect on the `const data = ...` line.  I'm happy to explain the general situation in my answer, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something about what you want.

Comment: @jcalz thanks again. Question is... Is there a way to create the type so that the ` as const` is not required in implementing it? If not, no worries. Your answer has satisfied the question. A great many thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an official answer when I get a chance.