# TypeScript Optional Sub-Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I know that there is a way to create a type-alias to have properties such as answer I have seen from another user in this post ([Typescript interface optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412872/typescript-interface-optional-properties-depending-on-other-property)) like below:

```
type Sample = {
  key1: true,
  key2?: string,
  key3: number
} | {
  key1: false,
  key2?: string,
  key3?: never
}
```

but how would I do it if the dependent properties are inside (as in, both key2 and key3 belong to key1, but key3 would exist only if key2 is true)? Would it be something like this:

```
type Sample = {
  key1: {
  key2?: true,
  key3: number
 }
} | {
  key1: {
  key2?: false,
  key3?: never
 }
}
```

Comment: You would just omit the `key3` property in the second type.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to just make the distinction inside like this:

```
type Sample = {
  key1: {
  key2?: true,
  key3: number
 } | {
  key2?: false,
  key3?: never
 }
}
```

Your code actually works too