# One property type is depent on other property value

Tags: typescript, validation, types

```
type resp = {valid: boolean, prop1?: string, prop2?: string}
```

in the above scenario. prop1 and prop2 are in type string or undefined.

I want to design like. if the valid value is true that means prop1 and prop2 will be strings that won't have an undefined value.

How can I create a type for this task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript interface optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412872/typescript-interface-optional-properties-depending-on-other-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I answered your question but in another question... If it's still relevant, here's the answer:

> You could create a union type:

```
type Resp = ({valid: boolean, prop1: string, prop2: string} & { valid: true }) | 
   ({valid: boolean, prop1?: string, prop2?: string} & { valid: false });

const o1: Resp = {
    valid: true,
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b'
}

const o2: Resp = {
    valid: false,
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4&ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYoF4oAoDeA3AhgGwEsATALigCMB7SvCHAOwBoowAnSsARjPmFYPoBzZmw4AmHnwGCAvlABkUDFFyFSUPgFdoMgJRQAPlABQUM5lXEyVGnSYt2XAPyT%20QkY7EuovN7IVKKvhWUABm%20PA6ugDcxsYAxpT0vFCU3LAISKgYpmZBamRaEIy5ZqJcZADkOJUleQ7iVeSVxjJxicnAqRIZiChKpfkh4XiRJTJAA)