# How to define a type as optional depending on the conditions

Tags: typescript

There is a type:

```
type PropsType = {
  dellSelectedOption: (id: string, idOptions: string[]) => void; 
  ownFilterData: Array<ActiveFilterAndPredFilterDataType>; 
  watchOverflow: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  removeOverflowing?: (ids: { [x: string]: string[] }[]) => void; 
  overflowLimit: number; 
  parentName: string;
};
```

How do I tell TypeScript that `removeOverflowing` must necessarily be present in props if `watchOverflow` is true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional properties depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412872/typescript-interface-optional-properties-depending-on-other-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

Let's define a type for the common props:

```
type CommonProps = {
  dellSelectedOption: (id: string, idOptions: string[]) => void;
  ownFilterData: Array<ActiveFilterAndPredFilterDataType>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  overflowLimit: number;
  parentName: string;
};
```

Now let's define a final type where the common props will be always present and one of the union will be present:

```
type PropsType = ActiveFilterAndPredFilterDataType &
  (
    | {
        watchOverflow: true;
        removeOverflowing: (ids: { [x: string]: string[] }[]) => void;
      }
    | {
        watchOverflow: false;
      }
  );
```

Comment: I like your answer. But for some reason it doesn't work. I get the message "The 'removeOverflowing' property does not exist for the 'PropsType' type"

Comment: It is expected, since removeOverflowing doesn't exist when the watchOveflow is false. This can be fixed by adding removeOveflowing?: never when the watchOverflow is false

Comment: Exactly what you specified in the form of "type of props Type = General Props &" ?

Comment: watchOverflow: false;
removeOverflowing?: never;
it worked for me. Thanks